# Xmpp Multi device message Read status Syc

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, ejabberd, openfire

I am trying to implement a messaging application like WhatsApp that supports multi-devices and platforms such as android ios web and electron app. User A can log in from any of this platform at any point in time such as can be online on multiple devices same time

A can be online in web and mobile app together

with XMPP carbon able to sync messages when all devices are online. in one platform message is delivered and the user a not viewed that message. after that a checking message on the second device how to identify the state of a message that was read or not

- A received message on the web but not read that chat
- A opens the mobile app and synced new messages from MAM
- MAM synced messages don't have any read status

Tried with XMPP message markers not able to solve these issue message makers are not part of MAM archived messages

XMPP server used is ejabberd

Answer (score 0):

For that exact reason [XEP-0333: Chat Markers](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0333.html) were created:

> Abstract: This specification describes a solution of marking the last received, displayed and acknowledged message in a chat.

And later on, from the same specification:

> The concept of delivery and read receipts has been popularised by other messaging services such as iMessage, Google Hangouts and Blackberry Messenger. These services provide a visual indication of when a message has been delivered to any of the recipients resources and (optionally) when it has been read. These visual indications (referred to herein as "Chat Markers") are synced between all of the sender's and recipient's resources automatically, so the state of a chat is always consistent. If one or more of the resources is not connected, it can fetch Chat Markers from the Message Archive upon reconnecting.

It should be supported by any MAM-supporting server, so this should include ejabberd.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am able to send and receive chat markers but the issue with archiving chat markers. by default ejabberd not storing chat markers (maybe I am wrong), after added </store> tag with marker message jabber storing markers but it keeping all markers in the archive. Because of that, every message have one more read status message . is it right way @Wojtek

Comment: Yes, it would cause certain overhead in the archive but that's "by design".